# how to do laravel with @foreach and @if

Tags: php, templates, if-statement, laravel, foreach

I have seen as "there are no posts" if they are available as comment even the URL is working property. 
I have discover on laravel.com there is not lack of information or example inside the @if and @else . http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures.

here is my code is

```
        @if ($post->comments)      
        <div class="text-center jumbotron">
            <h1 style="color:red;">There are no posts</h1>
        </div>
        @endif

    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{{ $comment->user->name }}}:
                <blockquote>{{{ $comment->text}}}</blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

however I have tried change as @if ($post->comments as $comment) is said "syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)" do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: You cannot use `as` in a simple if statement. The if statement works just as it would in normal php. What are you trying to do?

Comment: it still showing the name and text it refused to remove the "there are no posts".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or you could use the blade's `@forelse`  loop this way

```
@forelse($post->comments as $comment)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{{ $comment->user->name }}}:
            <blockquote>{{{ $comment->text}}}</blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    <div class="text-center jumbotron">
        <h1 style="color:red;">There are no posts</h1>
    </div>
@endforelse
```

Comment: make sure you are at least on laravel 4.2.7+ if you want to use `@forelse`

Comment: this does works! thanks! it does showing the either way "there is no posts" or "comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think this is what you wanted to do

```
@if ($post->comments)      
    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {{{ $comment->user->name }}}:
                <blockquote>{{{ $comment->text}}}</blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="text-center jumbotron">
        <h1 style="color:red;">There are no posts</h1>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I have tried as your code you gave to me. removed the "div class" and  it still no showing the "there are no posts". any idea?

Comment: Try this if statement instead `@if (!empty($post->comments))`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a `foreach` in the condition of an `if` statement
 Put the foreach in the entire `@if`, and check for NOT comments :

```
  @if (!$post->comments)      
    <div class="text-center jumbotron">
        <h1 style="color:red;">There are no posts</h1>
    </div>
  @else

@foreach ($post->comments as $comment)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{{ $comment->user->name }}}:
            <blockquote>{{{ $comment->text}}}</blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach 
@endif
```

This should be the control flow you are looking for.